# Inceptionv4 got wrong shape from CustomDataGenerator of keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm using InceptionV4 and my data is 8-channel npy file so I create a customdatagenerator to read my file

But when I training ,I got this error message

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, None, None, None) and (None, 6) are incompatible
```

As far as I know InceptionV4 accept data shape is(batch_size, height, width, channel),  in customdatagenerator I use same shape too and convert label_image to one_hot.

Here is my datagenerator , and I used same datagenerator in Unet few dats ago,there isn't any problem.

```
    params = {'dim': (299,299),
              'batch_size': 1,
              'n_classes': 6,
              'n_channels': 8,}
    class CustomDataGenerator(Sequence):
        def __init__(self, image_folders, label_folders, dir, dim=(299,299),  batch_size=1,n_classes=6,n_channels=8,shuffle=True):
            self.image_folders = image_folders
            ...
            self.on_epoch_end()

        def __len__(self):
            return int(np.ceil(len(self.image_paths) / self.batch_size))  

        def __getitem__(self, index):
            batch_image_paths = self.image_paths[index * self.batch_size: (index + 1) * self.batch_size]
            batch_label_paths = self.label_paths[index * self.batch_size: (index + 1) * self.batch_size]
            batch = zip(batch_image_paths, batch_label_paths)

            return self.get_data(batch)

        def on_epoch_end(self):
            self.image_paths = []
            self.label_paths = []
            for folder in self.image_folders:
                image_folder_path = os.path.join(self.dir, folder)
                image_files = os.listdir(image_folder_path)
                for file_name in image_files:
                    self.image_paths.append(os.path.join(image_folder_path, file_name))

            for folder in self.label_folders:
                ...

            if self.shuffle:
                ...

        def get_data(self, batch):
            X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_channels))
            y = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_classes))

            for i, (image_path, label_path) in enumerate(batch):
                image = np.load(image_path)
                label = np.load(label_path)
                self.y_true.append(label)

                label_grayscale = np.mean(label, axis=-1)
                min_val = label_grayscale.min()
                max_val = label_grayscale.max()
                scaled_label = (label_grayscale - min_val) / (max_val - min_val)  # Scale to [0, 1]
                scaled_label = (scaled_label * (self.n_classes - 1)).astype(int)  # Scale to [0, n_classes-1]
                label_one_hot = to_categorical(scaled_label, num_classes=self.n_classes)

                X[i,] = image
                y[i,] = label_one_hot

            return X, y
    train_datagen = CustomDataGenerator(image_folders, label_folders, train_dir, **params, shuffle = True)

    model = model_incetionV4
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001), loss=categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])
    model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('weight/123467_InceptionV4_test1.hdf5', monitor='loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
    model.fit(train_datagen, steps_per_epoch=30, epochs=500, validation_data=val_datagen, callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
```

```
class InceptionV4(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self,blocksList,num_classes):
        ...
    def call(self,inputs,training=None):
        x=self.stem(inputs)

        x=self.inceptionA(x)
        x=self.redA(x)
        x=self.inceptionB(x)
        x=self.redB(x)
        x=self.inceptionC(x)

        x=self.avgpool(x)
        x=self.dropout(x)
        x=self.dense(x)
        x=self.softmax(x)

model_incetionV4=InceptionV4(blocksList=[4,7,3],num_classes=6)
batch_size = 1
model_incetionV4.build(input_shape=(batch_size,299,299,8))
model_incetionV4.summary()
```

```
Model: "inception_v4"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
stem (Sequential)            (1, 35, 35, 384)          609760
_________________________________________________________________
inceptionA (Sequential)      (1, 35, 35, 384)          1277824   
_________________________________________________________________
reducetionA (Sequential)     (1, 17, 17, 1024)         2309280
_________________________________________________________________
inceptionB (Sequential)      (1, 17, 17, 1024)         18135040  
_________________________________________________________________
reducetionB (Sequential)     (1, 8, 8, 1536)           2571456
_________________________________________________________________
inceptionC (Sequential)      (1, 8, 8, 1536)           31940160  
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d (Gl multiple                  0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            multiple                  0
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                multiple                  9222
_________________________________________________________________
activation_21 (Activation)   multiple                  0
=================================================================
```

How to fix this problem?

Should I modify shape in Inceptionv4 or in customdatagenerator?

Comment: Looks like an output shape missmatch to me. What's the shape of 1 y from your `CustomDataGenerator` and the last layer of your model? You should get the values with `next(iter(train_data_gen))[0][1].shape` and `model.summary()` after `.build()`.

Comment: @mhenning label_one_hot(y) shape is(299,299,6)   6 is num_classes ,and I update model.summary()